# Docker: Run commands from multiple containers

Tags: backup, docker

I want to execute a command that uses commands from multiple containers.

E.g., I want to execute a backup script that used psql and pg_dump commands.

```
docker exec db_backup pg_dump
failed to exec: exec: "pg_dump": executable file not found in $PATH
```

`docker run` has an option `--link`. Is there a similar option for `exec`?

To clear this up, there are 3 containers:

- my_app
- db
- db_backup

I want to use pg commands located in `db` from my `db_backup` scripts.

Comment: how is `my_app` container related to the question?

Comment: `my_app` is a running application that is using `db` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not `--link` option for `docker exec`. If you want to backup using a special script:

1. Create a new image `db_backup` starting from the postgresql one (the one that the `db` container uses), adding the backup script to some folder.
2. Do `docker run --volumes-from db db_backup your_backup_script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

1) go to the `db` shell by using `sudo docker run -ti db /bin/bash`

2) type `which pg_dump` or `locate pg_dump` if the first fails

3) use the full path in your command `sudo docker exec db /full_path_to/pg_dump`

run the 3) inside your `db` container

note: on my Fedora the `pg_dump` points to `/usr/bin/pg_dump`

Comment: There is no pg command in backup container. pg command is located in "db" container.

Comment: But I want to run pg_dump from `db_backup` container.

Comment: I.e. I want a backup script to be in a separate container.